# JQuery/HTML - 'undefined is not a function'

Tags: jquery

My code isn't working and apparently it's because "undefined is not a function."

What's wrong with the JQuery code I got here?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contact").top("40%");
});
```

Comment: Have you included jQuery on your page?

Comment: There is no `top` jQuery method.

Comment: Most likely is because you did not include jquery on your page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#contact").css({ top: '40%' });
```

or

```
$("#contact").css('top', '40%');
```

Answer (score 0):

A little research into jQuery it's self could of helped. As @acarroz5 has mentioned, make sure you have included jQuery.

Anyhow also check that you are referencing an element id with "#" or a class with "."

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function()
   { 
     //Yours
     $("#contact").top("40%"); 

     //I prefer it like so...
     $('selector').css('top', '40'); 
   }); 
</script>
```

It's hard to really solve the issue without the HTML.